# 1.5 GB limit on file seek addressing?

Tags: file-system, reading

I am trying to transfer 5.4 GB file form an android internal memory (Sony Xperia Z2). But it seems that most applications have issues addressing the file beyond cca 1.5 GB. They just can't read the file after that point and end with an error. It applies to e.g. Zarchiver (failed compressing), Wifi File Server (stopped sending), etc.

However some apps can read those, e.g. the video player or some binary readers.

It seems that there might be a limit in standard API and the app needs to use different API for reading big files.

Is there some such limit of 1.5 GB? I have seen the 2 GB limit related to FAT32 + unsigned int, which seems not to be the case as I have files over 2 GB. It's just that most apps can't reach their content beyond those 1.5 GB.